# Identificar o maior número

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um software de monitoramento de recursos e estou com dificuldade para fazer ele identificar o maior número.

```
public string max()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");
        double avvv = 0;
        string abi = null;
        if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
            {

                String virtualMem = p.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString();
                String physicalMem = p.WorkingSet64.ToString();
                String cpu = p.TotalProcessorTime.ToString();
                abi = physicalMem;
            }
        }

        avvv = double.Parse(abi);
        avvv = avvv * 0.001 / 1024;
        return avvv.ToString();
    }
```

acima o código que eu gostaria de capturar o maior número, este é um código que monitora o uso de memória ram do processo, assim como faz o gerenciador de tarefas do Windows, só que eu quero obter o pico no momento em que o processo utiliza a maior contidade de memoria ram. Os valores são dinâmicos e sempre que mudasse para um maior eu quero que ele altere no valor máximo.

Dessa forma eu gostaria que ele exibisse.

[image]

Comment: Veja [isto](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38438/Monitoring-Process-Statistics-in-C-WPF)

Comment: Parece lógico comparar o próximo valor do foreach com o resultado anterior e atualizar o textbox caso o novo valor seja maior. Você consegue fazer este teste?

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
private static double Max_avvv=0;
public string max()
{

    System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");
    double avvv = 0;
    string abi = null;
    if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
        {

            String virtualMem = p.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString();
            String physicalMem = p.WorkingSet64.ToString();
            String cpu = p.TotalProcessorTime.ToString();
            abi = physicalMem;
        }
    }

    avvv = double.Parse(abi);
    avvv = avvv * 0.001 / 1024;

    if(Max_avvv<avvv)
       Max_avvv=avvv;

    return Max_avvv.ToString();
}
```